# Missing column after marge

Tags: python, pandas

**I have following data frames:**

```
------------Dataframe **dfc**---------
                                                       quantity    value
id name                                                                 
6  Lemet 10 L ogrzewacz nadumywalkowy elektryczny,...         4  1197.00
7  Lemet 5 L ogrzewacz nadumywalkowy elektryczny, ...         2   566.00
8  Lemet 10 L ogrzewacz podumywalkowy elektryczny,...         1   299.00
9  Lemet 5 L ogrzewacz podumywalkowy elektryczny, ...         8  2231.92
10 Lemet 50 L ECOWAY ogrzewacz wody elektryczny, p...         8  4563.20
```

**And one more:**

```
-------Dataframe **df**--------

    Koszt_przekliku_razem
id                       
6                    2.95
7                    0.59
8                    4.13
9                   18.88
14                   2.36
```

**I am using marge function to have one df with all columns - i am using ID as key:**

```
df_marge = pd.merge(dfc, df, on='id')
```

**This is the result:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
       quantity      value  Koszt_przekliku_razem
id                                               
206         132  426444.00                 504.42
16930        55  239461.00                 491.03
16929        14   58488.00                 391.94
15479       134   97332.75                 341.89
12017        10   29554.00                 295.52
```

**I can't figure out why i am missing name column on result df....**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the "name" column is actually part of your index along with "id" (that's why they are lower than the other columns when you print it). Merging only keeps columns, not indexes.
To make it a column before merging you can do this:

```
df = df.reset_index(level=0)
```

Then merging will give you the desired result.

Comment: It didn't worked but there is something in is as when i removed this one:
`dfc = (dfc.groupby(['id', 'name']).sum()) from dfc dataframe`

I get names on results but now i have to group df_merge

Answer (score 0):

The 'name' column is missing in the result df because it is not actually a column, it's an index. Pass left_index=True to keep the index of the first df.

```
df_merged = dfc.merge(df,how='left',on='id',left_index=True)
```